# Configure ssh key per git repo

Tags: git, ssh

I followed bellow tutorial to setup git server with ssh.

> https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

It was fine as long as I was the only one using the git repos.  Now I have more than one users who needs access to specific repos on the git server.  The above approach allows all users to access all the repos on the server.

How can I allow repo per user using their respective ssh key?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is on a Unix box, then `git` is just user on the system and Unix access controls are enforced.

1. Create a 2nd git user on system, e.g. `git2`.
2. Add the new user's key to the 2nd git user's authorized_keys file., but not to the 1st git user's authorized_keys file.  Optionally add your own key to the 2nd git user's authorized_keys file.
3. Initialize the 2nd user's repos as the 2nd git user. Ensure the permissions are set on the original repos such that the 2nd git user cannot access them.  This will require a bit of understanding of Unix shell, Unix file permissions, and the `chmod` command.
4. Use the 2nd git user when addressing the 2nd project, e.g. `git2@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git`.

To scale to multiple users, you'll either end up with setting up 1 git user per project (or set of projects). For many users, you would end up setting up a git user account per user and use group file permissions to control access to shared repos.  The latter will require using the `git init --shared=xxx` option.

Comment: It is a complicated approach but a possible solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Git does not do repo-level access like this. Look into something like [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) or [Gitlab CE](https://gitlab.com) to manage repository access via SSH key.